# Sending messages to the first channel. Discord.py

Tags: discord, bots, discord.py

I need to make it so that when the bot joins a new server, it writes a specific message to the very first text channel.

I tried to do something:

```js
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    print("Join to " + guild.name)
    guild_to_audiocontroller[guild] = AudioController(bot, guild)
    await guild_to_audiocontroller[guild].register_voice_channel(guild.voice_channels[0])
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        await guild.text_channels[0].send(join_message)
```

But it doesn't want to work, how do I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't want to work"? Do you have any error message?

Comment: @Mr_Spaar no, it just ignores these lines

Comment: If this code worked, every time your bot joined a server it will send your join message to every single server it is a member of, is that intentional?

Comment: @derw Oh, no, I need him to send only to the one he joined. You don't know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your bot has `Send Messages` permissions, all you need to send a message on join is:

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    await guild.text_channels[0].send("I have joined the server")
```